# Unity 3D Fatal error for some device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device

We are taking Fatal Signal error 6 SIGABRT on some devices with our latest **Unity2017.3.1f1** build.
All plugins are updated and only some devices (*Samsung S5*, *Samsung J5*, *Sony Experia J2*, *LG G3*, *LG G4*, ...) gives this error when game scene load after splash.
Most of devices are android 6.0, and some of them android 5.1, 5.0 and 7.1 versions.
Have you ever faced tihs kind of a problem before? How do you solve this. Please let us know.

Thanks for helping hands.

Comment: Please don't add a solution in the comments section. Rather post your solution as answer to your question. In this way people who have the same problem can see that you found a solution. After 2 days you also can accept you answer which makes it even easier to find your solution while searching for that or a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

We fix this issue with changing OpenGL ES version 2+ (with support 3.0) to ---> only OpenGL ES 2.0 Some OpenGL ES 3.0 supported devices are cause "FATAL ERROR SIG 11 sevg_maperr" wiki-zero.com/… Thanks for your help.